# Where did I go wrong in my solution? Linear transformation question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $T :R^3  \rightarrow R^3$ be a linear transformation and B be a basis for $R^3$ such that
$B = ((1,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1))$
and $E$ is the standard basis

$[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Find $T(x,y,z)$ for all $(x,y,z) \in R^3$

I've been trying to crack this one for a few hours now but I keep getting a wrong answer, my solution goes like this:
find $[T]$ as follows
$[T] = [T]_E = [I]^B_E[T]_B[I]^E_B$

and then compute $[T]\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ to find $T(x,y,z)$.
So first to find $[I]^B_E$ I put the vectors of B as the columns of a matrix so that
$[I]^B_E = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ after computing the inverse I get that $[I]^E_B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-1&1&-1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

so $[I]^B_E[T]_B[I]^E_B$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-1&1&-1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&-1&2\end{bmatrix} = [T]$

which leads to $[T]\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\x\\-y+2z\end{bmatrix}$
however the official solution to this problem is $T(x,y,z) = (x,x,-2x-y+2z)$

I'm guessing I went wrong either from assuming that building a matrix from the basis vectors as columns would give me $[I]^B_E$ or from my assumption that $[T] = [T]_E = [I]^B_E[T]_B[I]^E_B$ as both of these I came up with using experimentation without seeing a proof

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm sure your calculations are correct. In fact, take the first element of $B$, which is $(1,1,0)=E_1+E_2$. You have $[T]_B\cdot (1,1,0)=(1,1,-1)$ in base $B$. Convert it in base $E$ and verify that your solution is correct and the book's isn't

Answer (score 1):

What is the meaning of $[T]_B$? I suspect that $[T]_B = [T]_B^B$. If so, we have
$$[T]_E^E = [I]_B^E[T]_B^B[I]_E^B.$$
This is not what you wrote.

Here are my definitions and proof of the above equation:
By definition, if $T \in L(V, W)$ and $B_1 = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $B_2$ is a basis of $W$, then
$$[T]_{B_1}^{B_2} = J_{B_2}^{-1}TJ_{B_1},$$
where $J_{B_1} \colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to V$ is the isomorphism given by $$J_{B_1}e_j = v_j$$
and $J_{B_2}$ is defined analogously.

Thus if $T \in L(V, W)$, $S \in L(W, X)$, $B_1$ is a basis of $V$, $B_2$ is a basis of $W$, $B_3$ is a basis of $X$, we have
$$[ST]_{B_1}^{B_3} = [S]_{B_2}^{B_3}[T]_{B_1}^{B_2}.$$